# How do I make the table fit in the image created by tableGrob?

Tags: r, graphics

I am using tableGrob in R to create a .png image of a formatted table, for inclusion in a MS Word report. For small tables this works, but for larger ones they do not fit in the image. I haven't been able to find any parameters that allow me to either force it to fit automatically, or to manually control the height and width of the image window.

I would be very grateful if somebody could show me how to do this.

I am using R version 3.3.1, via Rstudio version 1.0.136, on Linux Mint on a 64-bit PC. R packages used include gridExtra, gridGraphics, gtable and png.

The table (tabsave) is a simple data frame with 34 rows and six columns, the first being chr and all the others num.

Here is what the output looks like. You can see how the table extends beyond both the upper and lower borders of the image:

[image: Output from code]

Here is the relevant code

```
gtab<-tableGrob(tabsave,rows=NULL,cols=nm,theme = ttheme_default(base_size=10)) # gtab is the graphical version of the table, for printing
png('test.png')
grid.draw(gtab)
dev.off()
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to give width and height parameters to the png function. They both default to 480, in the default unit of pixels (px).

So I just changed

```
png('test.png')
```

to

```
png('test.png',height=1200)
```

I played around with the width and height parameters until it gave the coverage I needed.

When the plotting is to the interactive plot device, rather than to a file (ie not using a function like png) it's just a matter of first resizing the plot window so it's big enough.